# How to send filename containing spaces as a parameter to convert command in imagemagick for linux OS

Tags: java, linux, shell, imagemagick, sh

How to send `file name` to the `convert` command as a parameter in Imagemagick (in a Linux-based OS) if the file name contains spaces. e.g.:

```
"/usr/temp/abc def.png"
```

I tried with different formats such as:

```
convert '/usr/temp/abc def.png'  /usr/temp/xyz.png
```

and:

```
convert /usr/temp/abc\ def.png'  /usr/temp/xyz.png
```

The above commands work as expected if we run them individually, however they do not work when sent through the application. These are the errors that we get:

```
unable to open image '/usr/temp/abc ,
```

and

```
unable to open image '/usr/temp/abc\ ,
```

Comment: In java it usually works. Can you give a code example in wich it fails?  On the other hand most shells: just put quotes around the name with the space.

Comment: What application?  If you need quotes in your application and quotes about the filename, be sure they are different quotes - single and double.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code from you application?

Comment: Please show the actual code. There usually are different calls to run a system command. Some of those parse the input line, others expect arguments as an already parsed array. The latter would probably solve your problem.

Comment: The problem is with how you send them through the application. Show us that.